# Import enum results in error 'Variable implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some simple enums and it works fine when I define them in the same file, but exporting / importing them results in many type-related compilation errors. Because it's only an issue when defining them in a separate file, the problem seems to be around how Webpack is pulling everything together. Here's a stripped down example.

common/enumerations.ts:

```
enum ViewBy {
    Alphabetical = "alphabetical",
    Year = "year"
};

export { ViewBy }
```

Test.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ViewBy } from './common/enumerations';

function Test(): JSX.Element {

    const [viewBy, setViewBy] = useState<ViewBy>(ViewBy.Alphabetical);

    return <></>;
}

export default Test;
```

Webpack compilation errors:

> Test.tsx(2,10) TS7034: Variable 'ViewBy' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
> Test.tsx(6,42) TS2749: 'ViewBy' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ViewBy'?
> Test.tsx(6,50) TS7005: Variable 'ViewBy' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems should be solved by adding `typeof` to `ViewBy`:

```
const [viewBy, setViewBy] = useState<typeof ViewBy>(ViewBy.Alphabetical);
```

Other could probably be solved by adding type `: any` to `ViewBy`:

```
const [viewBy, setViewBy] = useState<typeof ViewBy>(ViewBy.Alphabetical: any);
```

Comment: I tried casting everything to `ViewBy` and using `typeof ViewBy` like you suggest, but something seems to be fundamentally broken with how Webpack is pulling everything together and I'm not well versed in how it does it's compiling. Why would it need all this explicit casting only when defined in a separate file and imported?